# ajax request in javascript - asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, request

how to make a proper ajax request in javascript function?
can somebody give some clear and simple examples based on asp.net mvc technology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this be what you are looking for:

http://www.nikhilk.net/Ajax-MVC.aspx